# Concept Regular vs. Concept Semiregular

Tags: c++, c++20

Are there programming models that clearly differentiate the use of the `regular` concept and `semiregular` concept?

According to the [elements of programming](http://elementsofprogramming.com/eop-concepts.pdf), the `regular` concept has a clear mathematical definition. I gather that the `semiregular` concept (from the [draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/concepts.object#concept:semiregular)) is *a regular concept without the == comparator overload* .

The *ranges library* uses semiregular concepts for its implementation. However, I fail to understand why the distinction between the two is necessary if one could be derived from the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To constrain a template against a concept is to, essentially, make the claim that the template will freely use any of the expressions that the concept requires. If you are writing a template that, by the nature of the algorithm being implemented, has no need to do equality tests, then there is no point in excluding a type from that template solely on the basis of the viability of an expression that you don't want to use.

Not every type logically has the concept of equality testing. That's fine. But there are many places where the tools of regularity *except* for equality testing are useful. Hence there is a concept for types that are regular in every way other than testing for equality.

And `regular` is "derived from" (subsumes in C++-speak) `semiregular`. `regular` is explicitly defined as `semiregular` and `equality_comparable`.

Comment: I think you mean `all of the expressions` (instead of `any`) in the first line.

Comment: @Jerry: No, I meant "any". You can ask for a semi-regular type without default constructing one, and that's fine. The fact that you have reserved the right to default construct one does not *obligate* you to do so. The user must provide the capability, and you can choose to use it or not.